# how to align navbar toggle right side of navbar when it collapsed?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I use Bootstrap 4.As u see when navbar is collapsed toggle is middle of the navbar. But Actually I want navbar-toggle is right side of the navbar when it collapsed.I try many solution but does not work for me.Please give me a solution.....Thanks for the help :)

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <!--jQuery library--> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--Latest compiled and minified JavaScript--> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">AA</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
  
    </span>
 </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">    Home</a>
      </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About me</a>
      </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Education</a>
      </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Skills</a>
      </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Work</a>
      </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Me</a>
      </li>
     
    </ul>
   
  </div>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <!--jQuery library--> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--Latest compiled and minified JavaScript--> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row w-100 d-block"> 
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">AA</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler float-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
  
    </span>
 </button>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">    Home</a>
      </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About me</a>
      </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Education</a>
      </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Skills</a>
      </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Work</a>
      </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Me</a>
      </li>
     
    </ul>
   
  </div>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```